# Play with Object and Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object. Say its data.

```
const data = {}
```

I want a function ( Let it be `doThis()` ).
If i call `doThis('student' , 'James')`  , then data should be:

```
data = { student : ['James'] }
```

Again if i call `doThis('student' , 'Peter')`  , then data should be:

```
data = { student : ['James' , 'Peter'] }
```

If i call `doThis('planet' , 'earth')`, then data should be now:

```
data = { student : ['James , 'Peter'] , planet: ['earth'] }
```

Now again if i call `doThis('student' , 'Peter')`  , then Peter should be removed as it is already present in student properties. so the data should be:

```
data = { student : ['James'] , planet : ['earth'] }
```

PS: I solved it using the below function. Ignore the useCallback, it's just a react hook.

[image]

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far to implement the `doThis` function yourself / what you got stuck on?

Comment: I have solved it. thanks.

Comment: @SumanBhattarai Please attempt to solve your problems _before_ you ask a question. You are asking time and effort of volunteers here, while you apparently were able to solve this issue on your own. And when you try and it doesn't work, please add your attempt to your question as suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data={}
function doThis(key, value){
  if(key in data === true){
  if(data[key].filter(item =>item === value).length >0){
    data[key] = data[key].filter(item =>item !== value)
  }else{
    data[key] = [...data[key], value]
  }
}else{
  data[key] = [ value]
}
 return data

}

console.log(doThis("student", "Murangaza")) 
console.log(doThis("country", "RDC")) 
console.log(doThis("student", "Hans"))
```